# How to expand frame by dx,dy in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

For some reason the `Text()` view that I create sometimes doesn't fit the string correctly in its frame and instead draws the ellipsis -- while I am not explicitly defining the frame of the view.  So I would like to "expand" the frame by a dx/dy amount in the x/y directions -- is there a view modifier that I can use for that?  ex. `Text(" Jx3 ").expand(dx: +4, dy: 0)`  Or maybe I'm not supposed to use extra space in the string, but then the background shape is too narrow.

```
                        viewForPoints(displayHistory[index].displayPoints)
                            .overlay(
                                    Text(" \(displayHistory[index].abbreviation) ")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .font(FONTO)
                                    .offset(x: +8, y: +14)
                                    .background(
                                        Capsule()
                                            .fill(Color.white)
                                            .offset(x: +8, y: +14)
                                )
                        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use fixed size, as

```
.overlay(
   Text(" \(displayHistory[index].abbreviation) ")
      .fixedSize()
 )
```

Tested & works with some replicated code with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

*Note:* overlay uses same frame as its owner, so probably it worth considering ZStack for your case instead.